# I keep getting [Error] Id returned 1 exit status error and can't see where the issue is

Tags: c++

**I'm using Dev cpp**

I was given this assignment and my professor said that my `CalcTaxes` Variable was not declared correctly, but I cannot see the error. I've been having some trouble with prototypes. I would really appreciate the help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ADDR(var) &var


// These are the function declaration
void CalcTaxes(float gross,float deferred, float *fedtax, float *statetax, float *ssitax);
                float CalcFedtax(float gross,float deferred);
                float CalcStatetax(float fedtax);
                float CalcSSItax(float gross,float deffered);


// Driver Code
int main()
{
   float ft,st,ssit;

   CalcTaxes(1000,100,ADDR(ft),ADDR(st),ADDR(ssit));
   printf(" FedTax       = %8.2f\n",ft);
   printf(" StateTax   = %8.2f\n",st);
   printf(" SSITax       = %8.2f\n",ssit);

   fflush(stdin);
   getchar();
   return 0;
} // end of main()


// These are the function definations
void CalcTaxes()
{
  
   //Fillup the CalcTaxes()
   //According to instructor, CalcTaxes() should call
   //CalcFedTax(), CalcStateTax() and CalcSSITax() here.

}//end of CalcTaxes()

float CalcFedtax()
{
  
   //Fillup the body of CalcTaxes() here

}// end of CalcTaxes()

float CalcStatetax()
{
   //Fillup the body of CalcStateTax() here
  
}// end of CalcStateTax()

float CalcSSItax()
{
   //Fillup the body of CalcSSITax() here
  
}// end of CalcSSITax()
```

Comment: Your function definitions don't match the declarations. You're missing all the parameters.

Comment: Unrelated: why use such an outdated IDE?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis what IDE is he using, looks like VSC to me...

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is not defined. [C11 Standard - 7.21.5.2 The fflush function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.2) and see [std::fflush](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fflush) -- of course Microsoft has a non-standard implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Your function prototype has:

```
void CalcTaxes(float gross,float deferred, float *fedtax, float *statetax, float *ssitax);
```

5 parameters,
But when you defined it:

```
void CalcTaxes()
```

It has no parameters all of a sudden....

Comment: Actually, the first one is a declaration, and the second the definition (with a body `{}`).

Comment: @cigien yeah, exactly. The first one is actually a prototype or function declaration. You might want to edit your post, yunfei.

Comment: @cigien the body isn't that important, it is a wonder to me that the code actually compiles, because the definition and prototype dont match??

Comment: Yes, I was only pointing out that you has swapped the terms.

Comment: Because on my Text Editor if I try something like this, It will say 'void calcTaxes() has not being defined' or 'void calcTaxes(float gross, float deferred, float..) undefined symbols in artiche.....' or something like that, the point is I am curious why the code even compiles...

Answer (score 1):

Your function header `void CalcTaxes()` is missing its respective parameters.

it should look something like this:

```
 void CalcTaxes(float gross,float deferred, float *fedtax, float *statetax, float *ssitax)
{
//Your code..
}
```

Here is a basic use of functions. For example,

```
  #include <iostream> 

      void CalcTaxes(); //Your Prototype
    
    int main()
    {
    CalcTaxes();
    return 0;
    }
    
    void CalcTaxes()
    {
    std::cout << "Hello, from the function CalcTaxes!";
    }
```